# jquery ajax success - how to get the initiator in a common function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery ajax in a webapplication for a lot of different fields. For most of the calls the success functions are quite similiar, so it would make sense to refactor them to a common function. But, when some of the ajax call succeeds, I am calling

```
$(event.target).effect("highlight",{},3000);
```

to make a visual feedback that the call has succeeded, are there any way to do this with a common function as that as far as I know only will get back the return values from the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out the repeated logic each time, but you'll need to call it in a wrapper function that has access to the element you want to change.

```
//Generic success handler
function handler(element) {
  $(element).effect("highlight",{},3000)
}


$('#element1').on('click', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    //other options...
    success: function() { handler(event.target) }
  })
});

$('#element2').on('click', function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    //other options...
    success: function() { handler(event.target) }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)  global callback, refer to the link and you are good to go.
example:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event ) {
    $(event.target).effect("highlight",{},3000);
  }
});
```

This will  be called on any succesfull ajax call.